# React Native background colour affects overflow behaviour of absolute positioned child component

Tags: android, css, react-native

I am trying to implement a bottom navigation bar with an "overflowing" circle of action button.

I use the code

```
<View style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,
    flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column'}}>

    <View style={{height: 1,backgroundColor: '#000',opacity: 0.3}} />
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 50}}>
        <View style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 10,left: 0,right: 0,
            borderRadius: 75,
            width: 56,height: 56,
            backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    </View>
</View>
```

and it is able to give me the following effect:

[image: Without background colour]

So far so good. However, when I try to apply a background colour to the parent container, the "overflowing" part of the circle becomes hidden.

```
<View style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,
    flex: 1,flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>

    <View style={{height: 1,backgroundColor: '#000',opacity: 0.3}} />
    <View style={{flex: 1, height: 50}}>
        <View style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 10,left: 0,right: 0,
            borderRadius: 75,
            width: 56,height: 56,
            backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
    </View>
</View>
```

results in

[image: With background colour]

I have some difficulties in understanding the behaviour and would like to seek for an explanation for it.

On the other hand, I am able to achieve my desired appearance (background coloured parent + overflowing circle) by moving the circle to be a sibling of the current parent container. This behaviour is understandable to me but I would also like to know if there is any method I can keep the current DOM hierarchy while still having the effect I want.